# Void pointers in c

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-errors, void

I wrote these lines of code expecting them to work just fine but I keep getting an error that says "invalid use of void expression" and I have no clue why

```c
int main(){
   int a=12;
   void* ptr = &a;
   printf("%d",*ptr);
}
```

I thought void pointers can point to any type of data so what's the issue here? I even tried to cast the void pointer to an integer pointer but I still get the same error.

Comment: `printf("%d",*(int*)ptr);` would work. You cannot dereference a void pointer.

Answer (score 2):

> I thought void pointers can point to any type of data so what's the issue here.

A `void *` can point to any type of data<sup>1</sup>. But it only remembers the address, not the type. To use it with `*`, you must tell the compiler what type to use:

```
int a = 12;
void *ptr = &a;
printf("%d\n", * (int *) ptr);  // Use cast to specify type.
```

During execution, the program will not remember that `ptr` was assigned an address from an `int` and automatically know to load an `int` in the `printf` call. During compilation, the compiler will not remember this either. To use the pointer to access data, you must convert it back to an appropriate type, then use that.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> A pointer should retain all the qualifiers of any object it is set to point to. A pointer to a `const int x` or `volatile int x` ought to be assigned to a `const void *p` or a `volatile void *p`, respectively, not a `void *p` without the qualifiers.

Answer (score 1):

You can not dereference a void pointer, the underlying type (`void`) is incomplete.
You should either use a different type for your pointer (such as `int*`) or you should cast your void pointer to a complete type (again, probably `int*`).

Answer (score 1):

You can't dereference a `void*`, as you've seen, but casting it to an `int*` most definitely works:

```c
printf("%d",*(int*)ptr);
```

**[OnlineGDB demo](https://onlinegdb.com/aafN8MUpf)**